# How can i call func test() automatically on UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

How can `test()` function auto calls?  i don't want to call it on `viewdidLoad` So that whenever any viewController class initiate the `test()` function invokes. i tried alot & in objC `load()` function can do. but don't know how to achieve this in swift.
Below is sample code.

```
extension UIViewController{
    func test() {
        print("test")
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    //Automatically calls test()
}
```

Comment: You can’t do it in Swift. This is not your class.

Comment: @matt any chance by method swzzling or anyworkaround ?

Comment: What would you swizzle? You are not in charge of this class’s lifetime events. You cant make Cocoa call something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `UIViewController` and override the init method and call the test function from there.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        test()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        test()
    }

    func test() {
        print("test\(self)")
    }
}
```

All view controllers have to be a subclass of `BaseViewController` and when you initialize them they call `test()`

```
class MyViewController: BaseViewController {

}

let myBaseVC = BaseViewController()
let myVC = MyViewController()
```

Comment: I Dont want to generate new `BaseViewController `

Comment: @Amit You cannot manipulate the standard behavior of `UIViewController`. The solution with a BaseViewController is the only way to archive this.